# How to append the dragging LI element at the end of UL in Jquery sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In Jquery sortable How can I restrict the behavior of draggable 'LI', so that it should append to another 'ul' only at the end?

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

How can I make 'sortable1 li' elements should be appended only at the end of 'Sortable2' list but not in between 'Sortable2' li elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  receive: function( event, ui ) {
      $(ui.item).appendTo(this);
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/wPCtr/)**

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I want you ask one more question.. How can we make placeholder also should come only at the end. Now I am able to add  list elements at the end. But while dragging 'Sortable1' elements, 'Sortable2' list elemtns are moving down and up. I don't want to move already dropped elements.